# What is the difference between masking and tolerating failures?

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system, failure, fault-tolerance

*Distributed Systems* 5ed by Coulouris says on p21-22

> **1.5.5 Failure handling**
>
> **Detecting failures**: Some failures can be detected. For example, checksums can be  used to detect corrupted data in a message or a
>   file. Chapter 2 explains that it is  difficult or even impossible to
>   detect some other failures, such as a remote crashed  server in the
>   Internet. The challenge is to manage in the presence of failures that 
>   cannot be detected but may be suspected.
>
> **Masking failures**: Some failures that have been detected can be hidden or made less  severe. Two examples of hiding failures:
>
> 1. Messages can be retransmitted when they fail to arrive.
> 2. **File data can be written to a pair of disks** so that if one is corrupted, the other may still be correct.
>
> Just dropping a message that is corrupted is an example of making a
>   fault less severe –  it  could  be  retransmitted.  The  reader  will 
>   probably  realize  that  the  techniques  described  for  hiding 
>   failures  are  not  guaranteed  to  work  in  the  worst  cases;  for 
>   example, the data on the second disk may be corrupted too, or the
>   message may not  get through in a reasonable time however often it is
>   retransmitted.
>
> **Tolerating failures**: Most of the services in the Internet do exhibit failures – it would not be practical for them to attempt to
>   detect and hide all of the failures that might  occur  in  such  a 
>   large  network  with  so  many  components.  Their  clients  can  be 
>   designed to tolerate failures, which generally involves the users
>   tolerating them as  well. For example, when a web browser cannot
>   contact a web server, it does not make  the user wait for ever while
>   it keeps on trying – it informs the user about the problem,  leaving
>   them free to try again later. Services that tolerate failures are
>   discussed in the  paragraph on **redundancy** below.
>
> **Recovery from failures**: Recovery involves the design of software so that the state of  permanent  data  can  be  recovered  or  ‘rolled
>   back’  after  a  server  has  crashed.  In  general, the computations
>   performed by some programs will be incomplete when a  fault occurs,
>   and the permanent data that they update (files and other material
>   stored  in  permanent  storage)  may not  be  in  a consistent state. 
>   Recovery  is  described in  Chapter 17.
>
> **Redundancy**: Services  can  be  made  to  **tolerate**  failures  by  the  use  of  redundant  components. Consider the following examples:
>
> 1. There should always be at least two different routes between any two routers in  the Internet.
> 2. In  the  Domain  Name  System,  every  name  table  is  replicated  in  at  least  two  different servers.
> 3. **A database may be replicated** in several servers to ensure that the data remains  accessible after the failure of any single server; the
>      servers can be designed to  detect  faults  in  their  peers;  when  a
>      fault  is  detected  in  one  server,  clients  are  redirected to the
>      remaining servers.

What is the difference between masking and tolerating failures?

Can they both be done by redundancy? (The quote seems to say so. Then what differences are between them?)

Do they both need to perform recovery from failures?

I am also wondering [what difference and relation are between fault tolerance and (high) availability?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/403064/what-difference-and-relation-are-between-fault-tolerance-and-high-availability)

Comment: I wouldn't put too much stock in the exact definitions of these words.  By the author's own definitions, the numbered items in the Redundancy section could be characterized as "masking," not tolerating.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a comparison could help you understanding the difference. Imagine you're going to an e-commerce website. You found a product you want to buy and you click on the “Add to cart” button.

Under the hood, the browser sends an HTTP POST request which is processed by the reverse proxy and sent to an application server which may want to call other services and make some calls to a database.

Imagine that something during this task failed. Either the distant service haven't replied to the application server, or the application server was disconnected while processing your request, or the database change was not committed successfully.

**Masking failures**, here, means that the workflow will, by design, try to solve the issue. For instance, the application server could query the faulty service again or make another request to the database, or the application running in your browser can do another HTTP POST if the first one failed.

**Tolerating failures** would mean that you, as a user, will simply see a error message telling that, oh, sorry, we couldn't do what you asked, and could you please do it again? No worries, you can surely click the second time on the button.

Both have nothing to do with redundancy. Redundancy is a very different subject: you can experience failures with or without redundancy, and you can mask or tolerate failures with or without redundancy.

Recovery from failures apply to both situations. In the example above, you don't want to add the product twice to the cart when the user requested to add it once. Doing otherwise would be a bad user experience.

Comment: Are you going by this textbook's definitions?  Because they already seem to be ambiguous.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I do. It's strange, the definitions quoted in the question don't seem that ambiguous; actually, I found them rather clear, and I supposed that an extra example would be enough for the OP to understand them.

Comment: Case in point: *"File data can be written to a pair of disks"* -- **Masking.**  *"There should always be at least two different routes between any two routers in the Internet"* -- **Tolerance.**

Comment: "you, as a user, will simply see a error message". From my understanding this might be the case anyways. Depending of course what "user" means. I as a user do not want to get an inicident report for every failure of google's drives. But in a broader sense, the reporting is orthogonal to both concepts: Someone has to be informed - but not everybody.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand both are different in respect to the level of abtractions involved:

- "Masked" means here: Lower levels "mask" failure transparently for higher levels of the system. Failure on a lower level should be dealt on that level. A simple example for that are HDDs. There may be sectors failing without having you to worry immediately.
- "Tolerance" means here: Dealing with failure on the same level. Which in case of the HDD would be the embedded system of the HDD taking measures in case an incident happens.

Both concepts add up to the *resilience* of a system: the ablity to recover from failure.

The fact that your hard drive crashed shouldn't stop your system from "working". It is an "event" like any other and should be known to the right people.

Another example for tolerance is:

Say the job is to deliver a message. There is the *naive* solution to deliver it right away. In case it doesn't work, you stop trying.

The more elaborate version would be to *retry* later. Which is a kind of *fault tolerance* in that regard that you assume things might go wrong on the other side.

Then there is the possibility, that not only the recipient's system fails but that of the sender too. In order to deal with that you could leverage having redundancy on the sender's side to minimize failure.

This makes clear that being *fault* tolerant might not necessarily include redundancy but including redundancy making systems more fault tolerant to a wider range of faults.

Reporting of errors is orthogonal to both concepts.